# why below code returning set size as 5? even though hashcode and equals method is overridden it should return set size as 3

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, set, hashset

//why output of this code is 5 instead of 3
//why output of this code is 5 instead of 3
//why output of this code is 5 instead of 3//why output of this code is 5 instead of 3

```
public class Dummy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set set = new HashSet();

        set.add(new Student("abc"));

        set.add(new Student("abcd"));

        set.add(new Student("abc"));

        set.add(new Student("abc"));

        set.add(new Student("abcdef"));

        System.out.println(set.size());

    }
}

class Student
{
    private String age;

    public Student(String age)
    {
        this.age=age;
    }

    public boolean equals(Student stu)

    {
        System.out.println("equals from Student parameter called");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj)

    {
        System.out.println("equals from Object parameter called");

        return true;
    }

    public int hashcode()

    {
        System.out.println("hashcode called");

        return 17;

    }
}
```

Comment: `public int hashcode()` is NOT an override, that's why the @Override annotation should be used. I don't know how you expect a result of 3 though.

Answer (score 3):

It's not supposed to be `public int hashcode()`, it's `public int hashCode()`, so you've only overridden `equals()`. There may still be "equal" (based on your implementation) objects in different buckets since they don't all get same hash.

The `@Override` annotation is very helpful in these kinds of cases.

Comment: ok i'm stand corrected! now i know what mistake i did, i'm not able to identify proper overridden hashcode method. thanks for recognizing it! and also if i put proper overridden method i.e @override public int hashCode(), output is 1 why?

Comment: @user3721157 Because you've defined your class so that all instances are equal. You've also overloaded `equals()`, but that has nothing to do with anything here, since `HashSet` uses `equals(Object)`.